# JqGrid - clear toolbar filters hitting ESC?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

How can I clear all my filters (in JqGrid for PHP) by hitting the key: <kbd>ESC</kbd> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combination of these two links: [one](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/searching/search_toolbar/default.php) and [two](http://www.trirand.net/demo/php/jqgrid/)

Shows there is an event "clearToolbar" which can accomplish this.
I do not use the php version of jqgrid personally so i cannot test it, but from maninpulating the demo code i think this would work.

```
$search = << < SEARCH
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        jQuery('#grid')[0].clearToolbar();
        return false;
    }
});
SEARCH;
$grid - > setJSCode($search);
```

Comment: I had an unnecessary event in there that i forgot to remove out of the original example.  can you take another look at it and see if this works any better ?

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery fork perfectly for me slightly modified code

```
$('#jqxgrid').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('clearfilters');
      return false;
    }
});
```